# Storage on Nodemcu EEPROM

Tags: nodemcu, eeprom

Is there a way to access NodeMCU's EEPROM using Lua?

I would like to store data to the EEPROM on NodeMCU but I cannot find any libraries to do so in Lua.

Comment: Improve readability

Answer (score 2):

You have the Flash memory accessible through the normal [File](https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/master/en/modules/file/) interface and the NVram on the RTC chip accessible through the [RTC User Memory](https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/master/en/modules/rtcmem/) Module.